# Logs flooded with sh: sleep: command not found while no sleep command in JenkinsScript

Tags: linux, macos, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline script running from a Linux master to a mac pro slave.

When running from a macpro master the build runs absolutely fine, however when executed from the Linux master it keeps filling the logs with:

> "sh: sleep: command not found"

The only thing that it executes in the middle is :

```
GIT_COMMIT_HASH = sh (script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h'", returnStdout: true)
```

The entire Jenkins file does not have any sleep command. I'm unable to locate as to why that error happens.

I waited for more than 30 mins and the build never progresses except filling the logs with the same lines over and over.

From the mac Linux master the entire build completed in less than 9 min.

checked the version of plugins and they match, tried updating the ones that were old. Checked the path variables etc'.

I have the same issue from the Solaris based Jenkins master and the Linux based Jenkins master.

```
script {
GIT_COMMIT_HASH = sh (script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h'", returnStdout: true)
                    currentBuild.displayName = currentBuild.displayName + " $NODE_NAME $GIT_COMMIT_HASH"

...

}
```

Comment: Very similar to [this bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52576?jql=text%20~%20%22sleep%22)